# in java multithread applet all threads draw on same object

Tags: java, string, multithreading, applet, paint

it is my very first time to write a java applet; I have my multithread program and I must create an applet that shows the operation of program; in this moment I try to create a very basic applet that "simply" print the name of each thread.

My problem is that all threads draw on same object and overwrite this, I want that each thread write the own name separately (in this moment I can see only the name of last thread).

I've tried to create another graphics object but not working (and i think not is the right way).

This is the structure of my applet: I created a listener that is the interface and a responder that extends Applet and implements listener, in this I have init(), paint(Graphic g) and implementation of the function from listener's interface, the structure is:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Responder extends Applet implements Listener {
    public void init(){
        //some initialization

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        TH created = new TH(this);  //this=receiver
        created.start();
    }
}

    String toPrint;
    int pos=0;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
          g.drawString(toPrint, 20, pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void test(String s){
        toPrint=s;
        pos+=10;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

and each thread calls "test" function

Result is that in applet I have only one string with the name of last thread. I've searched in the web but can't find a clear example.

Can anyone suggest me the right way?

thanks (and sorry if there are english errors)

Edit: [Image to be clear](http://i.imgur.com/jOiEJkB.png)

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: my teacher want applet to show how my multithreads java program works.
I try to solve, if i can't solve, i will post the code. thanks

Comment: Well, I was not joking.  Please refer the teacher to that article.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    TH created = new TH(this);  //this=receiver
    created.start();
}
```

You created 10 different threads and pass the same applet object in constructor. You need something liske this:

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    TH created = new TH(new Responder());
    created.start();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but in this way not working. All threads call test method but ony one string is drawn and has the initialization value of the string toPrint. I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you want to draw all threads names in one applet or you want applet for each thread?

Comment: I want one applet, and each thread draw an own object (different from others), in this example their name

Comment: add synchronized to your test method

Comment: not solved :( synchronized ensure that only one thread at time can write a string but all write on same string, here the problem is how tell at java to create one object for each thread, to allow  each thread write in own object (string in this case) and not all on the same object.
Maybe it's possible create a graphic object that each thread can pass at paint function?